# Xcode iOS target. Simulator crashes with message 'dyld: Library not loaded (...) required code signature missing'

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, sdl-2, signature

I've got a SDL2 project, which runs fine for MacOS. But when I try to export to iOS the build is succesfull and then the simulator crashes with the following message:

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libSDL2.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/martinjoselizondocolomes/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F0FC3BBB-4809-4E45-B6BA-3709A2E82987/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DCAE530F-9AB5-4E23-AD51-0CBC8B58297D/my_sdl_ios_project.app/my_sdl_ios_project
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /Users/martinjoselizondocolomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my_sdl_ios_project-gupmbcbolzvwmdfiuqsguhjlxnxo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSDL2.dylib: required code signature missing for '/Users/martinjoselizondocolomes/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my_sdl_ios_project-gupmbcbolzvwmdfiuqsguhjlxnxo/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libSDL2.dylib'

I've tried to use the SDL template and example projects that come up in the SDL XCode IOS folder with no luck. Always the same issue.

Comment: is the lib set to "embed and sign" in the project target?

Comment: Sorry, where can I find that option? In Build Phases, I placed the libraries in the "Link Binary with Libraries" list. So, then?

Comment: in the files tab, click the project, then the target, and then General. Under frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded content (open the disclosure triangle) and you will see your framework there. Under Embed, you will have several options.

Comment: I did, but the result is the same. I still have the same message related to Signing: <<Signing for "Rectangles" (name of the Scheme) requires a development team. Select a development team in the project editor.>>

Comment: When I choose myself as a developer team it says:  <<Failed to create provisioning profile. The app ID "com.yourcompany.Rectangles" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.>> And below: <<No profiles for 'com.yourcompany.Rectangles' were found
Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.yourcompany.Rectangles'.>> I tried with and without  Automatically manage signing option.

Comment: Is it that I need a payed developper account?